# Why are my launch images not displayed?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have gotten launch images to show when the main screen was loading, in the past.

At present a black screen loads, stays for a second or two, then fades into the page background.

Under my assets, I have:

```
Default-568@2x.png
Default-Landscape.png
Default-Landscape@2x.png
Default-Portrait.png
Default-Portrait@2x.png
Default.png
Default@2x.png
```

This is intended to cover the basics at http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/sizes.html ; but in both portrait and landscape on a Retina displays, there is a screen of big black nothing before it loads a new background programmatically.

Is there anything additional that I can call that will let these display as the program launches and is loading?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow the following steps:

1) go to your project folder in xcode.

2) click on targets.

3) then go to summery tab.

4) scroll down and find launch images section, where you can set them.

Comment: I think I've found the area of Xcode where I can visually specify images.xcassets. However, while I can import images, I can't input them into the schema. How do I include images specifically into the schema that the program uses?

Comment: I am not clear with schema that you are talking about. But if you want to import images into your project folder also, then you cam do it right clicking on folder, then select add files. And while selecting file check mark for add files to project folder.

Answer (score 4):

Go in your project settings and there you can specify which images to load at launch.

Just including them into the bundle won't make it happen.

Answer (score 3):

if you go in you project's folder you can see if you still have the old splash screen (Black image that apple pt for your when you've made the project) delete it and you fix your problem